# Spring Security 4 Throws HTTP Status 404 Error in One Machine But Works Fine In Another

Tags: spring-security, web.xml, glassfish-4, applicationcontext

I am working in developing a Java application that runs on Glassfish 4.1 and uses Spring Security 4.2.0 for user authentication. Spring Security has been working fine in my development environment as well as in the production server for several months now, meaning that I can succesfully authenticate against user credentials stored in the respective server (development or production), and get redirected to the application's main page afterwards.

But this week, another developer in my company started working on the project, and after getting the source code and configuring his development environment, when he runs the application, after hitting the login button, he will get this every single time:

[image]

These are the files I used to configure Spring Security's authentication in my application:

**Web.xml**

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>   

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<listener> 
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class> 
</listener>
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
        <form-login 
            login-page="/login.jsp" 
            default-target-url="/BMSim.html"
            always-use-default-target="true"
            authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp?error" 
            username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" />
        <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/login.jsp?logout"  />
        <!-- disable csrf protection -->
        <csrf disabled="true"/>
        <!-- allow SmartGWT to create frames and call servlets from there -->
        <headers>
            <frame-options policy="SAMEORIGIN" />
        </headers>
    </http>

    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/BMSim" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                users-by-username-query="select username,password, enabled from users where username=?"
                authorities-by-username-query="select username, authority from authorities where username =?  " />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

**login.jsp**

```
<html>
    <body class="login t_center" onload="document.f.username.focus();">
        <form name="f" action="login" method="POST">
            <label>user: </label>
            <input id="username" type="text" name="username" />

            <label>password: </label>
            <input id="password" type="password" name="password" />

            <input class="login-button" name="submit" type="submit" value="login"/>

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**glassfish-web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app>
    <context-root>/BMSim</context-root>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

We have tried a lot of different things, but being no experts in Spring Security (or any part of Spring's framework, for that matter), we can't seem to be able to find the problem.

Any ideas on what can be causing this strange behavior (working in some environments, but not in others)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was finally solved and it turned out that it was a conflict between the version of the SQL Server driver defined in pom.xml (v4.2) and the actual jar that was placed on the Glassfish domain's lib folder (v4.0).